# Running Android Emulator on Azure pipeline has performance issues

Tags: android, azure, android-emulator, azure-vm

Running either a single/multiple android emulator's on azure pipeline has not been a smooth journey. When running an emulator the application to test runs very slowly causing the test framework to timeout.

After checking the emulator log I have found that the emulator runs on a single logical core on the Azure macOS VM.

Could anyone please suggest a solution to solve this ?

If it's unsolvable, Is there any other way to run a emulator on Azure VM ?

Comment: Running android emulator in world's most powerful supercomputer will have performance issues.

Comment: You could use [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) or [VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops) in Azure pipelines.

Comment: Is it possible without SHA or VMSS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not possible. The only way this could be achieved was to create a self-hosted machine managed via the Azure pipeline. The added advantage to this was I could also connect real devices.