# How to run android emulators on cloud platform?

Tags: android, debugging, cloud, virtual-machine

Can anyone explain me how to host an android emulator on Virtual Machine/cloud services and access it remotely for debugging?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433677/running-android-emulator-on-azure-pipeline-has-performance-issues for potential drawbacks/issues. Other than that, just search for documentation on how to achieve that on your specific cloud platform (here is one for [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops#test-on-the-android-emulator)).
Automation and instrumentation tests are one thing, but can you elaborate on your 2nd requirement, why can't you debug something on the emulator locally?

Comment: Hey. On the second requirement. It is mainly for testing purpose. when a tester requires to run his app on multiple emulators and multiple different devices. eg. samsung and xiaomi. I am working on this project mainly and i need some ideas.